# Android soft keyboard issue

Tags: android, keyboard

Hi friends,

I am working on an android application. I have a small issue with
 android soft keyboard. I have an `editText` and when i click on it, it
 shows me android soft keyboard. On the top of the soft keyboard, there
 is a text area that displays all the text i type using soft
 keyboard.It displays me what ever text i type using the keyboard. Is
 there a option to hide that text area on keyboard.

Kindly help me in this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Testing on a device or emulator ...???

Comment: i don't think so. it's something belongs to the keyboard and different devices uses different keyboards. so there is no way to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are talking about Auto Suggestion. Add the following code to your edit text in the layout file.

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

or in the code, you can use it like this,

```
setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

also you'd better read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType)

Answer (score 0):

Solution if you speak about auto-focus on edittext:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `EditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);` 
in your code.With the following code,one can stop the suggestions coming automatically from soft keyboard when you click on EditText